# using vb6 and oracle

Tags: datetime, grid

I have the records using the query 
    SELECT trunc(createdon,'hh') CREATEDON,count(*)
    FROM  WHERE LABSTATUS=1 AND
    CREATEDON >=TO_DATE('01/07/2010 10','DD/MM/YYYY hh')
    GROUP BY trunc(createdon,'hh')
in an hourly basis.. I need to place the count value in corresponding time column in the grid.
How can I do?? any idea

Comment: Could you please change the title to a more specific one. The question has nothing to do with vb6.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

Hours are in columns

```
SELECT TRUNC(createdon,'hh'), SUM(CASE WHEN hh=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) h1, 
                              SUM(CASE WHEN hh=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0) h2 .....
FROM TABLle1,
(SELECT 1 AS hh FROM dual
UNION 
SELECT 2 AS hh FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 3 AS hh FROM dual
....
) hours 
WHERE LABSTATUS=1 AND CREATEDON >=TO_DATE('01/07/2010 10','DD/MM/YYYY hh') AND
 TRUNC(createdon,'hh')= hours.hh
GROUP BY TRUNC(createdon,'hh')
```

Hours are in rows:

```
 SELECT hours.hh, SUM(CASE WHEN  TRUNC(createdon,'hh')= hours.hh THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) hh,                                  
    FROM TABLle1,
    (SELECT 1 AS hh FROM dual
    UNION 
    SELECT 2 AS hh FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS hh FROM dual
    ....
    ) hours 
    WHERE LABSTATUS=1 AND CREATEDON >=TO_DATE('01/07/2010 10','DD/MM/YYYY hh')      
    GROUP BY hours.hh
```

This query will result like this

- row 1 12

  row 2 0

  row 3 4

...

Comment: thanks.. But I got the count value and corresponding time.. But i need to place that count value in the grid..For eg: 01:59PM 2.. In the Grid column caption having 1:00-2:00Pm the count value 2 has to be place

Comment: SELECT hours.hh,SUM(CASE WHEN  TO_CHAR(createdon,'hh')= hours.hh THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS hh,
(SELECT 1 AS hh FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 2 AS hh FROM dual
UNION
 SELECT 3 AS hh FROM dual
 UNION
 SELECT 4 AS hh FROM DUAL
 UNION
SELECT 5 AS hh FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 6 AS hh FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 7 AS hh FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 8 AS hh FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 9 AS hh FROM DUAL
) hours
FROM TABLE1
WHERE LABSTATUS=1 AND CREATEDON >=TO_DATE('01/07/2010','DD/MM/YYYY hh') and hnum='475407D'
GROUP BY hours.hh
GROUP BY hours.hh
             *
ERROR at line 22:ORA-00904: "HOURS"."HH":invalid identifier